# How to access view reference of parent component from child component in angular2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-template

I have directory structure as follows:

[image: directory structure]

I assigned some method of parent component(app.component) to instance variable of it as follows:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit{
  @ViewChild('contentLoginModl') contentLoginModlCon: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('modlSignToApplyTg') modlSignToApplyTg: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('uploadCV') uploadCV: ElementRef;
  .....
  constructor(){ .... }
  .....
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.appState.set('opnLgnAppTmp',this.contentLoginModlCon);
    this.appState.set('opnUpldCvAppTmp',this.uploadCV);
    this.appState.set('opnLgnBfrAppTmp',this.modlSignToApplyTg);
  }
```

appState (service) is shared through all components but when i'm calling a function inside child compinent which access the refrence of parrent view it comes undefined as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
    at AppState._state.open (http://localhost:5003/static/main.prod.bundle.js:6:3788)
    at AppComponent.opnWithTry (http://localhost:5003/static/main.prod.bundle.js:2:17395)
    at AppComponent.opnLgnBfrApp (http://localhost:5003/static/main.prod.bundle.js:2:2714)
    at EditProfile.starItm (http://localhost:5003/static/main.prod.bundle.js:7:14899)
    at View_EditProfile26.handleEvent_24 (/AppModule/EditProfile/component.ngfactory.js:2700:51)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:5003/static/vendor.prod.bundle.js:27:22958)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:5003/static/polyfills.prod.bundle.js:4:12265)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:5003/static/vendor.prod.bundle.js:26:14260)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:5003/static/polyfills.prod.bundle.js:4:12170)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:5003/static/polyfills.prod.bundle.js:4:8197)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you access the state in the child component in the constructor or `ngOnInit()` then this is because `ngAfterViewInit()` of the parent wasn't yet executed and the properties are not yet set.

I'd suggest you use observables the child subscribes to and gets notified when values are emitted. If you use `BehaviorSubject` it doesn't matter if the child subscribes before or after the parent emits the properties.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service